# call system error with use another call

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I recently started writing some simple stochastic models using `use IFPORT` to call `random_seed` and `random_number(variable)`. At the end of my code, I added one `call system('gnuplot -p plot.gnu')` — this caused the following error:

```
>ifort example.f90
error #6552: The CALL statement is invoking a function subprogram as a subroutine.   [SYSTEM]
call system('gnuplot -p plot.gnu')
-----^
```

The code is as follows

```
program abc
use IFPORT

!declaration and initialization of variables    
call random_seed

do while (condition)
  call random_number(ranval)
  !computation
  !write on a file
end do

call system('gnuplot -p plot.gnu')
end program abc
```

This code cannot be compiled using `ifort`. If I comment `use IFPORT`, then the code can be compiled and `call system` caused no error. So, I am not certain if the `use IFPORT` is necessary to use `random_seed` and `random_number()`.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You can add a specific version tag if the question is specific to the old Fortran 90, but this one is not.

Comment: What has `IFPORT` in common with `random_seed` and `random_number`? As far as I know they are not related at all.

Comment: @VladimirF This code is written in .f90 file, so I thought it is supposed to be fortran90. I will be careful in future. Thank you.

Comment: Please show us **all error messages** including the command that caused them. I am sure the compiler printed more than just the number 6552.

Comment: Maybe your code is Fortran 90 indeed (but .f90 can be any later version as well), but the important thing is that more people will see your question if it is tagged [tag:fortran].

Comment: @VladimirF I am not certain about why it is necessary to have `use IFPORT`, because I followed an example of random number generator which contains that. After I include `call system(...)`, I could not compile the code. I googled and read about `use IFPORT`, but I could not understand.

Comment: Show us the error message, otherwise I don't know either where is the problem.

Comment: @VladimirF The command I used is `ifort example.f90` and the errors is error #6552: The CALL statement is invoking a function subprogram as a subroutine.   [SYSTEM]. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question with the relevant info. Are you sure the code you show is the **exact** code you are compiling and you sis not shorten it?

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, the code I showed is exactly what I have in my code. I put in the `!statement` to shorten the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, using `IFPORT` is not necessary at all.

`random_number()` and `random_seed()` are *intrinsic* procedures of Fortran 90 and later and no module has to be used to call them.

`system()` is a non-standard extension, but it is also an *intrinsic* procedure in all compilers I have used so far. Again, no module has to be used to call it.

`system()` can be used either as a function or as a subroutine depending on the compiler. The function version is called as

```
err = system(command)
```

where `err` is an integer variable.

Intel Fortran supports both versions. However, only one of them can be used at the same time! It is seems that `use IFPORT` includes an explicit declaration of `system()` as a function.

---

**Solution:**

1. **Don't `use IFPORT`**.
   Or only import those symbols from `IFPORT` which you actually need using `use IFPORT, only:`.
2. If you have to use it, use `system()` as a function.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir F. I would like to clarify that — if I want to use any _intrinsic_ procedure listed in [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Intrinsic-Procedures.html) in Fortran 90, then it is not necessary for me to use any module?

Comment: Almost. That list includes non-standard extensions of gfortran and you are using Intel. Intel might not support some of them at all (but mostly it does).